# swift - Unable to create IBOutletCollection of UILabels

Tags: swift, iboutletcollection

[image: Xcode Screen Shot]

The above screenshot shows the assistant editor to my view controller displayed.

I want to make an `IBOutletCollection` for the 'artist' labels and link them to the specific title but I'm unable to do so.

Comment: Do you know in advance how many artists you will have to show in this view?

Answer (score 0):

Use IBOutletCollection's equivalent in swift as follows:

> @IBOutlet var labelsArray: [UILabel]?

Connect all labels to the above property.